# Dynamics: Schwinger-Dyson-Expansion

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$

Consider a free generator $\delta_0:\mathcal{D}_0\to\mathcal{A}$ with $\overline{\mathcal{D}_0}=\mathcal{A}$.

Introduce a perturbation $\delta_V:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}:A\mapsto\imath[V,A]$ with $V=V^*\in\mathcal{A}$.

Denote to full generator by: $\delta:=\delta_0+\delta_V$

Investigate its dynamics: $\tau^{t}(A):=e^{it\delta}(A)$

How to derive the Schwinder-Dyon-expansion:
$$\tau^t(A)=\tau_0^t(A)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{0\leq s_1\leq\ldots\leq s_n\leq t}\imath[\tau^{s_1}(V),\ldots,\imath[\tau^{s_n}(V),\tau^{t}(A)]\ldots]\mathrm{d}s_1\ldots\mathrm{d}s_n$$
*(I'm so stuck on this since weeks and still no idea how to unfold this relation. Can you help me?)*

Also I still struggle with the rigorous construction of the dynamics:
$$A\in\mathcal{D}_0^\omega:\quad\tau^{t}(A):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\delta^k(A)$$
*(The problem here is that the analytic elements may be to few in several senses, or?)*

Moreover, can't it happen that it defines no dynamics at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hahaaa, I got it thanks to my supervisor. =D*

All formal calculations...

Consider the abstract cauchy problem:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\tau^t\tau_0^{-t}\right)(Z)=\tau^t(\delta-\delta_0)\tau_0^{-t}(Z)=\tau^t\imath\left[V,\tau_0^{-t}(Z)\right]=\left(\tau^t\tau_0^{-t}\right)\imath\left[\tau_0^{t}(V),Z\right]$$
so one gets the recursion relation:
$$\left(\tau^t\tau_0^{-t}\right)(Z)=Z+\int_0^t\mathrm{d}s\left(\tau^t\tau_0^{-t}\right)\imath\left[\tau_0^{s}(V),Z\right]$$
and therefore the expansion:
$$\left(\tau^t\tau_0^{-t}\right)(Z)=Z+\imath\int_0^t\mathrm{d}s\left[\tau_0^{s}(V),Z\right]+\imath^2\int_0^t\mathrm{d}s\int_0^s\mathrm{d}r\left[\tau_0^r(V),\left[\tau_0^{s}(V),Z\right]\right]+\ldots$$
That is after inserting the original argument:
$$Z:=\tau_0^t(X):\quad\tau^t(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\imath^n\int_{0\leq s_n\leq\ldots\leq s_1\leq s_0=t}\mathrm{d}s_1\ldots\mathrm{d}s_n\left[\tau_0^{s_n}(V),\ldots\left[\tau_0^{s_1}(V),\tau_0^t(X)\right]\ldots\right]$$
*(Mind the order of integral bounds w.r.t. the order of commutators.)*

*(Note that starting with the reverse expression leads to the same result after suitable substitutions.)*